# Manual way of defining a ManyToManyFied with a through in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

The model will hold what are the files uploaded and who uploaded it.
And each files are uploaded into a particular folder. So using the two below relation I should be able to get what are the files uploaded in a folder in a particular batch by which user.

I need to change the relation to use Django ManyToManyField by through relation.Is it possible for the below model relation to accommodate that (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

```
class FileUpload(Model):

    admin = ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='file_uploaded_by')
    upload_date_time = DateTimeField(
       auto_now_add=True,
       blank=True,
       verbose_name="Upload Date")

class FileUploadDetail(Model):

    which_file = ForeignKey(
        FileUpload, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='uploaded_file')
    folder_name = ForeignKey(
        Folder,
        on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='uploaded_to_folder')
```

Comment: What are you asking? FileUploadDetail is already a through model.

Comment: FileUpload <-> FileUploadDetail seems like a manual way of defining a ManyToManyField with a through configuration. I need to adjust it accordingly like https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: No, that's not at all a many-to-many relation. You have a one-to-many relation between FileUpload and FileUploadDetail; your many-to-many is between FileUpload and Folder.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman

Comment: @DanielRoseman is it possible to access FileUploadDetail through FileUpload if I can able to setup many-to-many relation between FileUpload and Folder.